# creating a second process in C

Tags: c

Im new in C programming and i have to do this:

> Write a program that creates a second process, and then in both processes outputs the process ID and the owners user ID.

I don't know if thats right and how to continue from here. Here is what i have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {

    int ChildPID;

    printf("This is the parent process number %d\n",getpid());
    if ((ChildPID = fork()) == -1) {
        perror("Could not fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (ChildPID == 0) {
        //----In the child process
        printf("This is the child process, number %d parent number %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
    } 

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: You have done it right for child process, what about current process?

Comment: what do you mean current process??

Comment: current process should be taken as the parent process.

Comment: The "owner's user ID" is provided by `getuid()`, rather than `getppid()`.

Answer (score 1):

The piece of code given below gives your solution. Here you can clearly identify parent code and child process code. Both are printing their corresponding pids.

```
void  ExecuteChild(void);
void  ExecuteParent(void);

int  main(void)
{
    pid_t  pid;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
        ExecuteChild();
    else
        ExecuteParent();
}

void  ExecuteChild(void)
{
    int   i;

    for (i = 1; i <= 200; i++)
        printf("CHILD[%d]: UserID[%d] printing - %d\n", getpid(),getuid(),i);
    printf(" ------------- Child Exiting -------------\n");
}

void  ExecuteParent(void)
{
    int   i;

    for (i = 1; i <= 200; i++)
        printf("PARENT[%d]: UserID[%d] printing - %d\n", getpid(),getuid(),i);
    printf(" ------------- Parent Exiting -------------\n");
}
```

Comment: thats what i have on my notes. Every process has a real user ID (the UID), an effective user ID (the EUID), a real user group ID (the GID), and an effective user group ID (the EGID). The user group ID is distinct from the process group ID. The user IDs can be accessed with the system calls:
int getuid(void)
which gets the UID of the process, and
int geteuid(void)
which gets the EUID of the process.

Comment: @AndreasPanayi: and you can use `getgid()` and `getegid()` to get the real and effective group IDs; and there's `getgroups()` to get all the groups.

Comment: so now that im getting the process id, can i just write getuid()  under the printf? for example printf("The real user of this process has ID %d\n",getuid());

Comment: This will give you gid of the user - printf("PARENT[%d]: UserID[%d] printing - %d\n", getpid(),getuid(),i);

Comment: You mean _This will give you UID ..._.